# como selecionar mais de uma opção no select multiple usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Quero fazer com que a função `seleciona( )`, ao clicar no botão Selecionar, selecione duas das opções abaixo. Entretando, quando tento fazer isso ele seleciona apenas uma opção.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Escolha uma ou mais cores:</label>
  <select name="cores" multiple readonly>
    <option value="1">Amarelo</option>
    <option value="2">Vermelho</option>
    <option value="3">Verde</option>
    <option value="4">Azul</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="seleciona()">selecionar</button>
</form>

<script>
function seleciona(){
    document.getElementsByName("cores")[0].value = 2,3;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer isso você vai ter que pegar os elementos específicos usando `document.getElementsByName("cores")[0].getElementsByTagName('option')` ou `document.querySelectorAll('select[name=cores] option')`

Então você vai ter que iterar em loop, pois ambas funções retornam "listas" de elementos, no caso vai retornar os options, em DOM a propriedade para "marcar" um elemento OPTION como selecionado é o `<elemento>.selected=true` para desmarcar é `<elemento>.selected=false`

No caso você que que os OPTIONs com value=2 e value=3 sejam selecionados, então basta em cada elemento checar se são os valores que deseja:

```js
var opcoes = document.getElementsByName("cores")[0].getElementsByTagName('option');

// poderia ser também
// var opcoes = document.querySelectorAll('select[name=cores] option');

function seleciona()
{
    for (var i = 0, j = opcoes.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (opcoes[i].value == "2" || opcoes[i].value == "3") {
            opcoes[i].selected = true;
        } else {
            opcoes[i].selected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <label for="cars">Escolha uma ou mais cores:</label>
      <select name="cores" multiple readonly>
        <option value="1">Amarelo</option>
        <option value="2">Vermelho</option>
        <option value="3">Verde</option>
        <option value="4">Azul</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <button type="button" onclick="seleciona()">selecionar</button>
    </form>
```

Note que fiz de forma bem explicita e usando if só para explicar (para ficar fácil de entender a lógica), mas dá para fazer mais simples assim:

```
for (var i = 0, j = opcoes.length; i < j; i++) {
    opcoes[i].selected = opcoes[i].value == "2" || opcoes[i].value == "3";
}
```

Se for 2 ou 3 seta true, caso contrário seta false

Agora se você tiver valores específicos vindos de outra fonte você pode usar você pode colocar eles em um array para dizer que esses devem ser os valores marcados, ficando assim:

```
var valoresDeOutraFonte = [2, 3];

for (var i = 0, j = opcoes.length; i < j; i++) {
    opcoes[i].selected = valoresDeOutraFonte.indexOf(opcoes[i].value) !== -1;
}
```

O `.indexOf()` vai buscar no array `valoresDeOutraFonte` o valor do option atual no loop, se estiver presente retorna 0 ou um numero maior, se não estiver presente retorna -1. Também existe a função [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), poderia fazer assim:

```
var valoresDeOutraFonte = [2, 3];

for (var i = 0, j = opcoes.length; i < j; i++) {
    opcoes[i].selected = valoresDeOutraFonte.includes(opcoes[i].value);
}
```

Mas se precisar rodar em navegadores mais antigos, como um Android antigo é provavel que includes não tenha suporte

Answer (score -3):

Você precisa fazer um `for` passando pelas opções e verificando se foram selecionadas.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <label for="cars">Escolha uma ou mais cores:</label>
      <select name="cores" multiple readonly>
        <option value="1">Amarelo</option>
        <option value="2">Vermelho</option>
        <option value="3">Verde</option>
        <option value="4">Azul</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <button type="button" onclick="seleciona()">selecionar</button>
    </form>


    <script>
    function seleciona() {
      let select = document.getElementsByName('cores')[0];
      let resultado = [];
      let opcoesDisponiveis = select && select.options;
      let opcao;

      for (let i=0; i<opcoesDisponiveis.length; i++) {
        opcao = opcoesDisponiveis[i];

        if (opcao.selected) {
          resultado.push(opcao.value || opcao.text);
        }
      }
      console.log(resultado);
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```